# Is there a search engine that keeps all historical data

Tags: google-search, search-engines

Is there a search engine where can the deleted historical information or pages there were removed from google search (or other search engines) can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google user can use [caches link to see old/deleted webpages](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en) for any website. There is no any specific time duration for how much time, the cache files will be index on Google server, but if content is useful for user then Google might don't delete it for many years, otherwise they will delete it in few months.

If you own content then you can request cache to removal from Google search console, they just down it temporary for 90 days. so webmaster can use noindex, robots.txt and 410 http error together to remove it permanently. More information you can find out [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6332384).

But there are other cralwers as well, for example [web archive machine](https://archive.org/web/), which crawl webpages and save it on their server, so any user can see how site was looking/have content in old days. To block such a cralwer find out their spider/bot/crawler name, and block it on your [robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/71385/58259)

Comment: Thank you both. I would like to know if there is a way to search content (word or phrase) that its indexes were removed from google search and now there are no matches (or message that content was removed) and in the past when you searched it you got list of sites/ results.

Comment: No once Google remove the cache files from their index, then they will never show it again in future, unless someone post same thing again on same domain name.

Comment: Thanks again @Goyllo, is there a software/ web site/ search engine that traps such cases and keeps the indexes and the sites that google removed?

Comment: Bing and Google both cache content, but as I said, if webmaster remove those pages then search engine show cache files to user. And it is not permanent for a life. Web machine save content permanently but if other request to remove it with legal notice, so they will also remove it. I don't know about other web/software.

Answer (score 2):

May be you mean [internet archive](https://archive.org/web/)